# Parsing error with && Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to conditional render a motion.div but it gives me a parsing error, this is de code:

```
    return (
    {showIntro && <motion.div className="intro"
    animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ delay: 4, duration: 1}}
    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
        <div className="text">
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="200" y1="10" x2="-200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={1.1}/>
            </motion.svg>
            <motion.h1 initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} transition={{ delay: 0.5, duration: 2}} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}> Welcome.</motion.h1>
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="-200" y1="10" x2="200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={0.9}/>
            </motion.svg>
        </div>
    </motion.div>}
)
```

and the problem is in line 36 (line 2 in this code sample):

```
  35 |     return (
  36 |         {showIntro && <motion.div className="intro"
     |                    ^
  37 |         animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
  38 |         transition={{ delay: 4, duration: 1}}
  39 |         exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
```

The error it gives me is:

```
    ERROR in [eslint]
    src\pages\Home.js
    Line 36:19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (36:19)
```

and my eslintconfig package.json file looks like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap output in curly braces when conditional is on the top of the output. Rewrite to this:

```
  return (
    showIntro && <motion.div className="intro"
    animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ delay: 4, duration: 1}}
    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
        <div className="text">
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="200" y1="10" x2="-200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={1.1}/>
            </motion.svg>
            <motion.h1 initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} transition={{ delay: 0.5, duration: 2}} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}> Welcome.</motion.h1>
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="-200" y1="10" x2="200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={0.9}/>
            </motion.svg>
        </div>
    </motion.div>
)
```

Just wrap into ( ... ), without curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your JSX like below [find explanation](https://www.querythreads.com/parsing-error-unexpected-token-expected/)

```
 return (
<>
    {showIntro && <motion.div className="intro"
    animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ delay: 4, duration: 1}}
    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
        <div className="text">
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="200" y1="10" x2="-200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={1.1}/>
            </motion.svg>
            <motion.h1 initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} transition={{ delay: 0.5, duration: 2}} exit={{ opacity: 0 }}> Welcome.</motion.h1>
            <motion.svg width="1000" height="20" viewBox="0 0 10 10" initial="hidden" animate="visible">
                <motion.line x1="-200" y1="10" x2="200" y2="10" stroke="white" variants={draw} custom={0.9}/>
            </motion.svg>
        </div>
    </motion.div>}
</>
)
```